# Alternating row colors on LoadingRow event in WPF DataGrid doubling colors on rows

Tags: wpf, .net-core, datagrid

I am alternating row colors programatically through the LoadingRow event.
The reason for this is because I need to specify a specific color on some rows, i.e. rows marked for deletion and rows with modified data.

This works fine, until I scroll up in the DataGrid and I get this very weird interaction where it doubles or triples up the row colors.

[image]

It displays correctly when scrolling downward.

I have tried using AlternationIndex with AlternationCount set to 2, and using a bool to flip between, both result in the exact same issue.

If I dont set this in the LoadingRow event and use the DataGrid AlternatingRowBackground the row color bleeds into other rows as I scroll through the table.

```
private void dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the DataRow corresponding to the DataGridRow that is loading.
            var item = e.Row.Item as ExpandoObject;
            if (loadedTable.ToDelete.Contains(item))
            {
                e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.OrangeRed);
                return;
            }
            else if (loadedTable.Modified.Contains(loadedTable.Rows.IndexOf(item)))
            {
                e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightYellow);
                return;
            }
            else if (e.Row.AlternationIndex == 0)
            {
                e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.WhiteSmoke);
            }
            else if (e.Row.AlternationIndex == 1)
            {
                e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
            }
        }
```

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="All" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Gray" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray"
                                 FontSize="15" FrozenColumnCount ="1" x:Name="xmlData" EnableRowVirtualization="True" AlternationCount="1"
                                 AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" Background="WhiteSmoke"
                                 Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,-31,5,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="2" SelectionUnit="Cell" 
                                 PreviewKeyDown="DataGridKeyDown_Event" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                                 LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow"/>
```

Comment: Can add xaml for your datagrid? Are you doing any virtualization? Also other than doing code behind have you looked at using a datagrid row style? I normally use that to and then use datatriggers within it to change the background color. It will honor your original alternating or default background color and only change when the data trigger is triggered. In the Binding of the datatrigger you can use a converter to do complex logic.

Comment: @JMIII Added the XML now. I think what you and J.H. suggested is the route to go, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is because DataGrid reuses DataGridRow objects (could try EnableRowVirtualization="False").

What you want to do is set the DataGridRow's background based on it's data/item using styles.

Here is a test app that does what you want to do.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp9.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp9"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:VM />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AlternationCount="2">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <!-- Converter used to convert the DataRow's Item and the VM.ToDelete list to bool (true = it is deleted) -->
            <local:IsDeletedConverter x:Key="IsDeletedConverter" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!-- Setup the background color for normal rows using AlternationIndex -->
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <!-- Override the above background colors if it is in the deleted list - NOTE: these styles are processed in order, make sure this is after the above triggers -->
                    <DataTrigger Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsDeletedConverter}">
                                <!-- This is the DataContext of the DataGridRow - the item (ExpandoObject) we will check for in the deleted list -->
                                <Binding />
                                <!-- Need the deleted list, which is in VM -->
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" Path="DataContext" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <DataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed" />
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Col1}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Binding="{Binding Col2}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

CODE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp9
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class VM
    {
        public List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject> Items { get; set; }
        public List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject> ToDelete { get; set; }

        public VM()
        {
            Items = new List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>();
            ToDelete = new List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                var eo = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
                var d = eo as IDictionary<string, object>;
                d["Col1"] = $"String {i}";
                d["Col2"] = i;
                Items.Add(eo);

                // Add some items to ToDelete list
                if (i % 10 == 0)
                {
                    ToDelete.Add(eo);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class IsDeletedConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length != 2)
                throw new ArgumentException($"IsDeletedConverter is expecting 2 values but got {values.Length} values!", nameof(values));

            if (values[0] is System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject eo && values[1] is VM vm)
            {
                if (vm.ToDelete.Contains(eo))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL I was thinking about posting a style sample with datatriggers but you beat me to it. +1 best way to do by far.

Comment: @JMIII - LOL. I saw your comment right before I submitted. Also, honoring the original bg/alt bg -- I tried that but it didn't work... I'm sure it was because I didn't set them in a style but right on the DataGrid (which, you can then NOT override in a style).

Comment: @JH you are correct when doing you have to set in the same style that holds the data triggers after the triggers themselves with just a standard setter property for the background. I don't know why that is but it works. I use it in my apps with a custom nlog target to write to a wpf window when needing to debug and highlight different rows based off the logging level

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is the way to go.

Comment: While this fixed the main issue here, it still leaves an issue where rows whose background was set in code continue to stay that color when scrolling through a RowVirtualization table, they dont change back to their alternating colors.

Is there a way to refresh the row style based on those triggers when changes are made?

Comment: Don’t set row’s background in code? Once you do, it no longer uses its style (as you noticed). You can add additional data triggers using different converters to get different background colors. Order is important.

Comment: I've looked into EventTriggers but changing the row background via those gives the same issue. Sorry to be a pest, but am I approaching this wrong? I need the color of the row to change when the data is modified or when a key combo is pressed to mark it for deletion.